# Is there a good alternative of 'TextAloud' text to voice software?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-to-speech

I'm looking for an alternative under Ubuntu for a software that I used to have long time ago under Windows. Its called TextAluod. It has natural voices that you can use. So far, I tried ESPEAK  through terminal, but is too robotic, so I would like to know which alternatives are available for our dear Ubuntu and how natural the voices are?

Answer (score 2):

How about `NR 6.6`? From [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=790397) webpage:

> Regarding other good-sounding text-to-speech software, I looked everywhere, tried everything and NR was easily the best.

Answer (score 1):

[Cepstral](https://www.cepstral.com/demos/) has some really nice voices, but they're $30 each.  They're designed to be used with IVRs, but they can behave like espeak by typing `padsp swift "Some text"` from the command line.  There is a demo of the voices on the website.

They do have some for 'personal use', but they seem to be a full version behind the ones for professional use.  Not sure if they require payment as well, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: thanks really useful information, it seems a good idea, since it runs natively

Answer (score 1):

I would check out http://www.spokentext.net/. I found it very good. I have a lot of old writings that I wanted to make into Audio book and this site lets me do this. You have your choice of many different voices (Male and Female). Worth taking a look at.

Comment: I'll check it one of these days

Comment: Checked today, link seems dead...

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I encounter the exact same problem you are describing myself, one year ago, and I created a new TTS utility which could replace the exact command. It works offline, for free with AI-based high-quality voice. You can you it everywhere: Firefox browser, PDF reader, chrome, LibreOffice, etc.

Feel free to have a look, I just created a video tutorial with installation steps and DEMO: https://youtu.be/hb1ZVwUcPCU

Download link and Project page: https://github.com/MattePalte/Verbify-TTS

Feel free to leave comment/open issue to discuss new ideas, problems or constructive criticism.

Hoping it will help you.